# d3.js The values on the x-axis and graph are not equal

Tags: json, d3.js

I have now completed the graph.
However, the value of the resulting graph is not equal to the scale of the x axis.
Is there any way to synchronize the values ​​and scales of the graph to each other?
The value is out, but it does not match the scale of the x axis.

```html
[
 {"name":"a","energy":200},
 {"name":"a","energy":400},
 {"name":"a","energy":450},
 {"name":"a","energy":300},
 {"name":"a","energy":120}
]
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>d3_bar chart</title>
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
 
 
 
 
</head>
<body>
 <svg id="test1" width="250" height="250"></svg>
 
 <script>
  var data = d3.json("data_F.json", function (error,data){
   
   alert(data);
   alert(error);
   
   //var max = d3.max(data, function(d){return d.energy;})
   //var sum = d3.sum(data, function(d){return d.energy;});
   
   //alert(max);
   //alert(sum);
   
   var dataTotal = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){return d.name;})
    .rollup(function(v){
     return d3.sum(v, function(d){return d.energy;});
    })
    .entries(data);
    
   console.log(JSON.stringify(dataTotal));
   
   var max = d3.max(data, function(d){return d.energy;});
   
   console.log(JSON.stringify(max));
   
   var sum = d3.sum(data, function(d){return d.energy;});
   
   console.log(JSON.stringify(sum));
   
   
   var width=250,
    height=250,
    padding=20
    maximum=5000; // 그래프백분율최대값
    
   
   var canvas = d3.select("#test1")
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width",width)
     .attr("height",height);
     
   //var format = d3.format("%");
   //var formattedX = format(dataTotal.value);
   
   //alert(formattedX);
   
   var rect = canvas.selectAll("rect")
     .data(dataTotal)
     .enter()
     .append("rect")
     .attr("width", function(d){return ((d.value/maximum)*100);})
     .attr("height",30)
     .attr("x",20)
     .attr("y",function(d,i){return i*20;})
     .attr("fill","steelblue");
     
   var text = canvas.selectAll("text")
     .data(dataTotal)
     .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("fill","black")
      .attr("x",100)
      .attr("y",function(d,i){return i*50+80;})
      .text(function(d){return (((d.value/maximum)*100)+"%");});
   
   var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
     .range([padding,230])
     .domain([0,100]);
   
   var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale)
    ;
    //.tickFormat(function(d){return Math.round(d*100/max)}+"%");
    
   var gX = canvas.append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate(0,"+(30)+")")
    .call(xAxis);
  
  })
 </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the width of your x-axis is 400

`var x_scale_width=400;`

The  width of 100% is the width of the axis less the padding you left :

`var total_width=x_scale_width-padding`;

The width of X% is `total_width*X/100`

in your case `X=(d.value/maximum)*100;`

so the width of X% is `((x_scale_width)-padding)*(d.value/maximum)`

#### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amani1988/wdbsd7bz/)